How do methods and/or configurations scroll programmatically to ListView.builder indexes in flutter
How do methods and/or configurations scroll programmatically to ListView.builder indexes in flutter
 ListView.builder(
                    itemExtent: 60,
                    itemCount: controller.lotQueryList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (c, i) {}
)

help me

Explain more please so we can help you out

Can you please explain it more, so that everyone can understand it

Thank you. If I have a listview.builder list of about 5000 items, how can I jump to the 2000th item using a function or configuration?

If you use a constant item height for the items, you can use below method.
const double itemHeight = 50.0;

void _jumpToIndex(int index) {
    // Estimate the offset using item size and index
    double offset = index * itemHeight;
    _scrollController.jumpTo(offset);
}

if you have dynamic height for each item, you can simply use scrollable_positioned_list package.
final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();

itemScrollController.scrollTo(
  index: 2000,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);

